# Motorola Droid Bionic Custom ROM

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, motorola-droid

How can I install a custom ROM on my Motorola Droid Bionic without the help of a computer? Should it be done by pressing the volume and power buttons to get to recovery the normal way, or should I have a specific recovery app? Obviously I need root. The page on the CyanogenMod site mentions both SafeStrap and TWRP, but I'm still unclear on what their roles are and if I even need both.